# return enum or pass enum by reference?

Tags: c++, enums

I have a procedure which performs some task, but performs it in two slightly different ways depending on its input. Specifically it extends a suffix in a suffix tree; if the suffix ends at a node the case is simple, but when the suffix ends within a leaf edge some additional work is required. I mention this detail to explain why I have included these two behaviours in a single function (it mirrors "Rule 2" of Dan Gusfield's description of Ukkonen's algorithm for suffix tree construction: http://www.stanford.edu/~mjkay/gusfield.pdf).

Anyway, once the function completes this work, the caller needs to know which of the two cases were followed. I thought an enum would be a good way to share this information, as it makes the cases explicit (as opposed to arbitrarily mapping the cases to bools or ints).

TLDR: To share information with the caller, should I pass an enum by reference to this procedure or return an enum? I feel like passing an enum by reference is better because it avoids having a 'function with side effects' but would like to know if there is generally 'right' way of doing this. Or, alternatively, does this really suggest that I should be replacing my single procedure with two separate procedures?

Comment: I'd prefer to return the enum - it sounds like a piece of the result of the algorithm.  Passing by reference just seems a bit odd in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion it makes more sense to return the enum, since it is the result from calling the function. Using a reference would make much more sense if you were passing a value to the function, and the function was supposed to modify that value.

You can see a similar example in [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) method from `unordered_map` in the C++ standard library:

```
template <class P> 
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( P&& value );
```

That method returns a boolean (within a pair) stating whether the value was inserted in the map or not. This actually a very similar case as the one you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better tu return the enum as the result of the function since it's more readable and simpler to write:

```
MyEnum res = myfunc();
```

Then

```
MyEnum res;
myfunc(res);
```

Comment: Great, concise explanation for why the return is better here. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface for further reading.

Answer (score 2):

> I feel like passing an enum by reference is better because it avoids having a 'function with side effects'

Quite the opposite, actually... generally, if you modify your arguments, that's a side effect.

There's no reason to avoid returning anything.

Comment: right, but if it doesn't return anything then it ONLY modifies some state or has an observable interaction with the outside world (like a procedure), but if it returns as well, then it both returns and modifies state (which I seem to remember is 'bad' for some reason).

Comment: You're remembering wrong. Functions are supposed to return values; that's their job. Because of the limitations of C++, sometimes you have to "disguise" returned values as reference output params, but that's never _better_; you do it because you have no choice.

Comment: Or sometimes you have to take in a callback and pass the "return" value to the callback instead... same reasoning as @abarnert said.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are just integer values when they're stored in memory, and compilers enforce check on the range of values used for the enum. Having said that integer data types are efficient and safe to return by value.

Unless you function really returns more than one value, the caller need not pass the enum as a reference and get back the result.

```
YourEnum result
result = MyFunc()
```

PS: The rule I usually follow for deciding whether a value should be returned, or make the caller pass a pointer/reference and return the value is if the data returned is a simple or complex data type. ;)

Comment: That rule may not be a good one. Have a look at [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) to see why returning a vector (for instance) may not have any overhead.

Comment: It is a double-edged sword - if you see the string example mentioned at the end. ;)